# How to display gear change.?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a car racing game in unity and I've written following JAVASCRIPT code to move car. I'm able to display speed of a car but not gear change using my logic. So help me to correct it. Gear variable is only displaying '0' in text area. But not incrementing by one after checking condition.

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("right")) {
                   transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
                }
                 if(Input.GetKeyDown("left")) {
                   transform.Rotate(0, -1, 0);
                }
     switch(currentMode) {
             case ShipModes.Idle:
                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) { 
                   currentMode = ShipModes.Moving;
                }
                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
                    currentMode = ShipModes.Reverse;
                }
                break;
             case ShipModes.Moving:
                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
                   currentMode = ShipModes.Idle;
                }

                break;
              case ShipModes.Reverse:
                 if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
                    currentMode = ShipModes.Idle;
                 }
                 break;
       }
       //Movement phase 
       switch(currentMode) {
             case ShipModes.Idle:
                 currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(currentSpeed, 0, Time.deltaTime);
                   break;
             case ShipModes.Moving:
                 currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(currentSpeed, maxSpeed, Time.deltaTime); //Or MoveTowards
                 break;
             case ShipModes.Reverse:
                 currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(currentSpeed, maxReverseSpeed, Time.deltaTime); //Or MoveTowards
                 break;
       }
       //Actually move


        score.text="SPEED "+Mathf.Abs(currentSpeed).ToString("F0");

        //Gear change display starts from here
        var gr=0;
        var sp=currentSpeed;
        while(gr!=5)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if(currentSpeed>=sp)
            {
                gear.text="GEAR "+gr;
            }
            sp=sp+5;
            gr=gr+1;
        }
```

Comment: `if (currentSpeed >= sp)` - I'm not sure how you think this is ever going to evaluate to true. Initially, `sp` and `currentSpeed` are the same. From there, `sp` only ever gets bigger, so it's never going to be smaller than or equal to `currentSpeed`, except for the very first time through the loop, when `gr` is 0 and has not been incremented yet.

Comment: That I get it and thanks for correcting me but how can I solve this problem to display gear cahnges.?

Comment: Sorry, really cant tell from the code you've shown. The current approach even with a change to the `if` condition I mentioned will not work. Because you're running a loop, you will keep running it until you meet the terminating condition, i.e `gr != 5` at which point you will only get a `GEAR 5` message. So,in your model of a car you must have a mechanism by which to change gears, either manually or automatically. At the point that the gear changes there, you should simply update the text with the new gear. :)

Comment: okay thanks for help.